# jQuery Validate error placement and required text placement

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I've created a form which I'm using jQuery validate for and I needed to move the error messaging for two of the fields so I found an example on here that showed how to do that and it worked great.  Except, now, the "required" fields are not all working.  Here is my form code:

```
<form id="myForm"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="x_po_num">Account Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x_po_num" id="x_po_num">       
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="x_invoice_num">Invoice Number</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">9</div> 
        <input class="form-control" name="x_invoice_num" id="x_invoice_num" data-error="#invError">
      </div>         
      <div id="invError"></div>
  </div>        
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="x_reference_3">Reference Number</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="x_reference_3" id="x_reference_3" placeholder="Optional" >          
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="x_amount">Amount</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>              
        <input class="form-control" name="x_amount" id="x_amount" data-error="#amtError">
      </div>
      <div id="amtError"></div>
  </div>     
  <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay With Your Credit Card" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

And here is my jQuery validate code:

```
$( "#myForm" ).validate({
    rules: {
      x_po_num: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 11,
        maxlength: 11
      },
      x_invoice_num: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,            
        maxlength: 9,
        minlength: 7,
        normalizer: function( value ) {
          var inv = value;
          inv = "9" + inv;             
          return inv;             
        } 
      },
      x_reference_3: {
        digits: true,
        maxlength: 9,
      },
      x_amount: {
        required: true,
        number: true
      }
    },
    messages: {              
      x_po_num: {
        required: "Please enter an account number",
        minlength: "The account number must be 11 digits long",
        maxlength: "The account number must be 11 digits long",
        digits: "Please enter digits only, no spaces"
      },
      x_invoice_num: {
        required: "Please enter an invoice number",         
        maxlength: "The invoice number must be 10 digits or less",
        minlength: "The invoice number must be at least 8 digits long",
        digits: "Please enter digits only, no spaces"
      },
      x_reference_3: {
        digits: "Please enter digits only",
        maxlength: "The reference number must be 9 digits or less"
      },
      x_amount:{
        required: "Please enter an amount"
      }

    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }   
});
```

**Here is the problem:**

The two fields which I needed the error messaging moved (Invoice Number and Amount) are now in the correct spots.  However, if I open the form and hit submit without entering any data, I am expecting the Invoice Number to come up with an error saying "Please enter an invoice number" but it does not. It does not display any error at all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the normalizer function.  I took it out and added the digit with my onSubmit and problem solved.